# ggplot2 - Invert color palett if negative

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make something like this, but with custom legend. Can I add something to a legend that is not in the plot?
To make this I use "fill=1:nrow(df)" to be able to choose exactly what color goes on what bar. 
But I would like to show a legend as well, only with 7 colors and choose which colors go with which label.

[image]

A working example. 
Is it possible to show a legend here with only one label and choose which color is showing in the legend?

Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
           Var2 = rep(c("Year 2011", "Year 2012"),2),
           value = c(0.1,-0.1,0.3,0.05),
           Var3 = c("#719500", "#AC1A2F", "#719500", "#719500"))

df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=factor(1:nrow(df)))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",
             position = position_dodge(width=0.9), show.legend = F) + 
    scale_fill_manual(drop = FALSE, 
                      values = df$Var3, 
                      labels = levels(df$Var2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **csgroen** I found a solution that is what I am looking for. Many thanks to him.

What I needed:
Plot for a few questions on x-axis showing change for a few years. Value could be positive or negative. So I wanted dark-green/red for the year 2011, lighter-green/red for 2012 etc.

My problem was showing a specific color for a year and showing the correct legend. Because each year has two potential fill colors, but I only want the legend to show one of them.

#### The data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = paste("Question", c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")),
                 Var2 = rep(c("Year: 2011", "Year: 2012", "Year: 2013"), 2),
                 value = c(0.1, -0.1, 0.3, 0.05, -0.17, 0.25))
```

As suggested in an answer, I create a new fill variable that gets labelled depending on if value is positive or negative.
The variable df$type needs to be a factor with all possible levels.

```
df$type <- ifelse(df$value < 0,
                  paste(df$Var2, "negative"),
                  paste(df$Var2, "positive"))
df$type <- factor(
  df$type, 
  c(paste("Year:", 2011, c("positive", "negative")),
    paste("Year:", 2012, c("positive", "negative")),
    paste("Year:", 2013, c("positive", "negative")))
)
```

#### The plot

I use drop=FALSE to show all levels of df$type, regardless if they are shown in the plot or not.
breaks=c() only shows the positive levels in the legend. And labels=c() names them correctly.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("Year: 2011 positive" = "#719500",
               "Year: 2011 negative" = "#AC1A2F",
               "Year: 2012 positive" = "#89B400",
               "Year: 2012 negative" = "#D22039",
               "Year: 2013 positive" = "#A9DE00",
               "Year: 2013 negative" = "#E96D7F"),
    breaks = c("Year: 2011 positive",
               "Year: 2012 positive",
               "Year: 2013 positive"),
    labels = c("2011", "2012", "2013"),
    drop=FALSE)
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure this will solve your problem, but a different way to think of this is to use the `label` you want for each color as your `fill` and specify which colors correspond to which labels in `scale_fill_manual`.

In your example, if we have one color for 'positive' and one for 'negative', this would be, first we'd get the 'type' with mutate. Then, we'd plot using 'type' as the 'fill'. To specify the colors, we can use `scale_fill_manual`

```
df <- mutate(df, type = ifelse(value > 0, "positive", "negative"))
df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",
             position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(positive = "#719500", negative = "#AC1A2F"))
```

If you plot this, the legend may not be in the order you want. What I'd suggest is to transform the 'type' column into a factor and specify the order wanted in the levels, i.e.:

```
df$type <- factor(df$type, levels = c("positive", "negative"))
```

which would yield 'positive' before 'negative' in our legend of `type`.

Comment: Ahhh perfect! Thank you so much. I was stuck on this for a long time, going in circles. You put me on the right track. I will edit the question with the complete code if someone stumbles upon this problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about actually mapping a color gradient instead of manually assigning colors?

```
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=value, group = value)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity",
         position = position_dodge(width=0.9), show.legend = T)+
scale_fill_gradient2( low= '#ff2d2d', high = '#9ee0ff', mid = 'grey50',midpoint=0, guide='colorbar')
```

Comment: Thank you for the good suggestion. However, I need to show a discrete legend with specific colors. So the year 2011 is always fill="#719500" when positive and dark-red when negative.